# I want to display my selected values from a multi dropbox into a disabled text field but I am unable to do it. Please tell me what i am missing

Tags: javascript, html

Following is my HTML code for a form. This form contains some country fields that are multiple dropdown select inputs.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <link rel="icon" href="\images\trademark_icon.png" type="image/gif" sizes="16x16">


    </head>
    <style>

   <!--Blah Blah -->
    </style>
    <body>

    <h2 ><img src="images/hero_logo.png" class="herologo" ><span class="form-title">Trademark Filing Application</span></h2><br>

    <div>
    <p style="padding-left:20px"><span class="error">* required field.</span></p>

      <form action="insert.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

        <!-- Department  -->

        <b>Select Department:</b><span class="error"> *</span>
        <select id="dept" name="department" required>
        <option value="">Please Select...</option>
          <option value="ceo">CEO Office</option>
          <option value="global">Global</option>
          <option value="marketing">Marketing</option>
          <option value="parts">Parts</option>

        </select>
        <br><br><br>

        <!-- Class  -->

        <b>Select Class:</b><span class="error"> *</span><br><br>
        <input type="radio" id="wordradio" name="classs" value="Word" required>Word
        <input type="radio" id="deviceradio" name="classs" value="Device" style="margin-left:20px">Device
        <input type="radio" id="logoradio" name="classs" value="Logo" style="margin-left:20px">Logo
        <input type="radio" id="soundradio" name="classs" value="Sound" style="margin-left:20px">Sound
        <input type="radio" id="taglineradio" name="classs" value="Tagline" style="margin-left:20px">Tagline
        <br><br><br>


        <!-- Preferences  -->


        <b>Enter Preference(s):</b><br>
        1. <input type="text" id="pref1" name="preference1" style="width:30%" placeholder="Preference 1" required>
        <input type="file" id="prefbtn1" name="files[]" multiple="" required>
        <span class="error">*</span>
        <br>

        2. <input type="text" id="pref2" name="preference2" style="width:30%" placeholder="Preference 2">
        <input type="file" id="prefbtn2" name="files[]" multiple="" >

        <br>
        3. <input type="text" id="pref3" name="preference3" style="width:30%" placeholder="Preference 3">
        <input type="file" id="prefbtn3" name="files[]" multiple="" >

        <br>
        4. <input type="text" id="pref4" name="preference4" style="width:30%" placeholder="Preference 4">
        <input type="file" id="prefbtn4" name="files[]" multiple="" >

        <br>
        5. <input type="text" id="pref5" name="preference5" style="width:30%" placeholder="Preference 5">
        <input type="file" id="prefbtn5" name="files[]" multiple="" >

        <br><br><br>


        <!-- Goods and Services  -->


        <b>Enter The Types of Goods & Services :</b><span class="error"> *</span>
        <br>
        <input type="text" id="goodss" name="goodsnservice" placeholder="Select the type of Goods and Services" required>

        <br><br><br>


        <!-- Mark in Use?  -->

       <b>Is Mark In Use?</b><span class="error"> *</span><br><br>
        <input type="radio" id="marky" name="mark" value="yes" onclick="disableNo()" required>Yes


        <!-- Mark in Use?: YES  -->


        <div id="markyes" class="show-hide" style="background-color:white;width:600px ;margin-left:40px; border:1px solid black; border-radius:5px"><br>
        <b>When Did You Use It?</b>
        <input type="date" name="yeswhen" style="margin-left:10px" id="markyesdate" required><span class="error"> *</span><br><br>

        <b>Where Did You Use It?</b><span class="error"> *</span><br>
        <select name="yescountry[]" style="width:20%" id="markyescountry" multiple required>
            <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
            <option value="Yemen">Yemen</option>
            <option value="Zaire">Zaire</option>
            <option value="Zambia">Zambia</option>
            <option value="Zimbabwe">Zimbabwe</option>
            </select><br><br>

                <b>Proof Of First Use:</b><span class="error"> *</span><br>
        <input type="file" id="markyesproof" name="files[]" value="Upload one or more files" multiple="" required>
        </div><br>


                <!-- Mark in Use?: NO  -->


        <input type="radio" name="mark" value="no" onclick="disableYes()" >No<br>
        <div id="markno" class="show-hide" style="background-color:white;width:600px ;margin-left:40px; border:1px solid black; border-radius:5px"><br>
        <b>When Are You Expected To Use It?</b>
        <input type="date" name="nowhen" style="margin-left:10px" id="marknodate" required><span class="error"> *</span><br><br>

        <b>Where will You Use It?</b><span class="error"> *</span><br>

        <select name="nocountry[]" style="width:20%" id="marknocountry" multiple required>
            <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
            <option value="Albania">Albania</option>
            <option value="Algeria">Algeria</option>
            <option value="American">American Samoa</option>
            <option value="Zaire">Zaire</option>
            <option value="Zambia">Zambia</option>
            <option value="Zimbabwe">Zimbabwe</option>
            </select><br><br>

        </div><br>


                <!-- Mark Applied Country  -->


        <b style="text-height:50%">Mark Applied Country:</b><br>

        <select name="markappliedcountry" id="multi-country" class="dropdown-country" style="width:20%" multiple >

            <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
            <option value="Albania">Albania</option>
            <option value="Algeria">Algeria</option>
            <option value="Zambia">Zambia</option>
            <option value="Zimbabwe">Zimbabwe</option>
            </select><br><br>

        <br><br><br>
        <input type="text" id="selected_values" name="multiple_selected_values" disabled/><br/><br/>

        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
      </form>
    </div>

    <script>
    function disableNo() {
        document.getElementById("marknocountry").required = false;
        document.getElementById("marknodate").required = false;      
    }

    function disableYes() {
        document.getElementById("markyescountry").required = false;
        document.getElementById("markyesdate").required = false;
        document.getElementById("markyesproof").required = false;      
    }


    var selText;
    $('select').on('change', function() {
        selText ="";
      $("#multi-country").each(function () {
         var $this = $(this);   
         if(selText !=""){
          selText = selText.concat(","); 
          selText = selText.concat($this.text());
         }
         else
            selText=$this.text();
      });
      //alert(selText);
      document.getElementById("selected_values").value=selText;
    });

    </script>


    </body>
    </html>
```

[image: I want these selected values to be displayed in the field below.]

I was trying to use it first on Applied Country(the one at the last), so that if it worked, I would replicate it to other fields too. Also, is there any way that I can reuse the same dropdown list for three different select inputs?

Answer (score 1):

I think that should do the job:

```
<select name="markappliedcountry" id="multi-country" class="dropdown-country" style="width:20%" multiple >
            <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
            <option value="Albania">Albania</option>
            <option value="Algeria">Algeria</option>
            <option value="Zambia">Zambia</option>
            <option value="Zimbabwe">Zimbabwe</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="selected_values" name="multiple_selected_values" disabled/>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('select').on('change', function() {
    $('input').val($(this).val());
  });
});
```

[JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/zre0q1m0/5/#&togetherjs=U4VRxoUjR2)

Comment: well kinda... you have JSFiddle example attached where you can see the result... 
I used tag names as selectors but you can change it to ids or classes if you want

Comment: How to use jQuery Egde in my project. I believe it is not working because I don't know how to use jQuery Edge, because of it above java script isn't working

Answer (score 0):

So, after 29 days after asking this question and trying many alternatives, I finally found the answer:

This is my Html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<title>Trademark Filing Application</title>

<link rel="icon" href="\images\trademark_icon.png" type="image/gif" sizes="16x16">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">


</head>
<body>


<h2 ><img src="images/hero_logo.png" class="herologo" ><span class="form-title">Trademark Filing Application</span></h2><br>

<div>
<p style="padding-left:20px"><span class="error">* required field.</span></p>

  <form action="insert.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <!-- Department  -->

    <b>Select Department:</b><span class="error"> *</span>
    <select id="dept" name="department" required>
    <option value="">Please Select...</option>
      <option value="CEO Office">CEO Office</option>
      <option value="Global">Global</option>
      <option value="Marketing">Marketing</option>
      <option value="Parts">Parts</option>

    </select>
    <br><br><br>


    <!-- Class  -->

    <b>Select Class:</b><span class="error"> *</span><br><br>
    <input type="radio" id="wordradio" name="classs" value="Word" required>Word
    <input type="radio" id="deviceradio" name="classs" value="Device" style="margin-left:20px">Device
    <input type="radio" id="logoradio" name="classs" value="Logo" style="margin-left:20px">Logo
    <input type="radio" id="soundradio" name="classs" value="Sound" style="margin-left:20px">Sound
    <input type="radio" id="taglineradio" name="classs" value="Tagline" style="margin-left:20px">Tagline
    <br><br><br>


    <!-- Preferences  -->


    <b>Enter Preference(s):</b><br>
    1. <input type="text" id="pref1" name="preference1" style="width:30%" placeholder="Preference 1" required>
    <input type="file" id="prefbtn1" name="image" multiple="" required>
    <span class="error">*</span>
    <br>

    2. <input type="text" id="pref2" name="preference2" style="width:30%" placeholder="Preference 2">
    <input type="file" id="prefbtn2" name="preferTwo[]" multiple="" >

    <br>
    3. <input type="text" id="pref3" name="preference3" style="width:30%" placeholder="Preference 3">
    <input type="file" id="prefbtn3" name="preferThree[]" multiple="" >

    <br>
    4. <input type="text" id="pref4" name="preference4" style="width:30%" placeholder="Preference 4">
    <input type="file" id="prefbtn4" name="preferFour[]" multiple="" >

    <br>
    5. <input type="text" id="pref5" name="preference5" style="width:30%" placeholder="Preference 5">
    <input type="file" id="prefbtn5" name="preferFive[]" multiple="" >

    <br><br><br>


    <!-- Goods and Services  -->


    <b>Enter The Types of Goods & Services :</b><span class="error"> *</span>
    <br>
    <input type="text" id="goodss" name="goodsnservice" placeholder="Select the type of Goods and Services" required>

    <br><br><br>


    <!-- Mark in Use?  -->

   <b>Is Mark In Use?</b><span class="error"> *</span><br><br>
    <input type="radio" id="marky" name="mark" value="yes" onclick="disableNo()" required>Yes


    <!-- Mark in Use?: YES  -->


    <div id="markyes" class="show-hide" style="background-color:white;width:600px ;margin-left:40px; border:1px solid black; border-radius:5px"><br>
    <b>When Did You Use It?</b>
    <input type="date" name="yeswhen" style="margin-left:10px" id="markyesdate" required><span class="error"> *</span><br><br>

    <b>Where Did You Use It?</b><span class="error"> *</span><br>

    <input type="text" style="height:10px;width:50%" id="selected_yes" name="yes_country_values" disabled /> <br/>
    <select name="yescountry" id="yescountry" style="width:40%" multiple required>
        <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
        <option value="Albania">Albania</option>
        <option value="Tajikistan">Tajikistan</option>
        <option value="Turkey">Turkey</option>
        <option value="Turkmenistan">Turkmenistan</option>
        <option value="Wallis &amp; Futana Is">Wallis &amp; Futana Is</option>
        <option value="Yemen">Yemen</option>
        <option value="Zaire">Zaire</option>
        <option value="Zambia">Zambia</option>
        <option value="Zimbabwe">Zimbabwe</option>
        </select><br><br>

            <b>Proof Of First Use:</b><span class="error"> *</span><br>
    <input type="file" id="markyesproof" name="yesProof[]" value="Upload proof" multiple="" required>
    </div><br>


            <!-- Mark in Use?: NO  -->


    <input type="radio" name="mark" value="no" onclick="disableYes()" >No<br>
    <div id="markno" class="show-hide" style="background-color:white;width:600px ;margin-left:40px; border:1px solid black; border-radius:5px"><br>
    <b>When Are You Expected To Use It?</b>
    <input type="date" name="nowhen" style="margin-left:10px" id="marknodate" required><span class="error"> *</span><br><br>

    <b>Where will You Use It?</b><span class="error"> *</span><br>

    <input type="text" style="height:10px;width:50%" id="selected_no" name="no_country_values" disabled /><br/>

        <select name="marknocountry" id="nocountry" style="width:40%" multiple required>
        <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
        <option value="Albania">Albania</option>
        <option value="Algeria">Algeria</option>
        <option value="American">American Samoa</option>
        <option value="Andorra">Andorra</option>
        <option value="Angola">Angola</option>
        <option value="Anguilla">Anguilla</option>
        <option value="Antigua">Antigua &amp; Barbuda</option>
        <option value="Argentina">Argentina</option>
        <option value="Armenia">Armenia</option>
        <option value="Aruba">Aruba</option>
        <option value="Australia">Australia</option>
        <option value="Austria">Austria</option>
        <option value="Azerbaijan">Azerbaijan</option>
        <option value="Bahamas">Bahamas</option>
        <option value="Bahrain">Bahrain</option>
        <option value="Bangladesh">Bangladesh</option>
        <option value="Barbados">Barbados</option>
        <option value="Belarus">Belarus</option>
        <option value="Belgium">Belgium</option>
        <option value="Belize">Belize</option>
        <option value="Benin">Benin</option>
        <option value="Bermuda">Bermuda</option>
        <option value="Bhutan">Bhutan</option>
        <option value="Bolivia">Bolivia</option>
        <option value="Bonaire">Bonaire</option>
        <option value="Bosnia &amp; Herzegovina">Bosnia &amp; Herzegovina</option>
        <option value="Botswana">Botswana</option>
        <option value="Brazil">Brazil</option>
        <option value="British Indian Ocean Ter">British Indian Ocean Ter</option>
        <option value="Brunei">Brunei</option>
        <option value="Bulgaria">Bulgaria</option>
        <option value="Burkina Faso">Burkina Faso</option>
        <option value="Burundi">Burundi</option>
        <option value="Cambodia">Cambodia</option>
        <option value="Cameroon">Cameroon</option>
        <option value="Canada">Canada</option>
        <option value="Canary Islands">Canary Islands</option>
        <option value="Cape Verde">Cape Verde</option>
        <option value="Cayman Islands">Cayman Islands</option>
        <option value="Central African Republic">Central African Republic</option>
        <option value="Chad">Chad</option>
        <option value="Channel Islands">Channel Islands</option>
        <option value="Chile">Chile</option>
        <option value="China">China</option>
        <option value="Christmas Island">Christmas Island</option>
        <option value="Cocos Island">Cocos Island</option>
        <option value="Colombia">Colombia</option>
        <option value="Comoros">Comoros</option>
        <option value="Congo">Congo</option>
        <option value="Cook Islands">Cook Islands</option>
        <option value="Costa Rica">Costa Rica</option>
        <option value="Cote D'Ivoire">Cote D'Ivoire</option>
        <option value="Croatia">Croatia</option>
        <option value="Cuba">Cuba</option>
        <option value="Curacao">Curacao</option>
        <option value="Cyprus">Cyprus</option>
        <option value="Czech Republic">Czech Republic</option>
        <option value="Denmark">Denmark</option>
        <option value="Djibouti">Djibouti</option>
        <option value="Dominica">Dominica</option>
        <option value="Dominican Republic">Dominican Republic</option>
        <option value="East Timor">East Timor</option>
        <option value="Ecuador">Ecuador</option>
        <option value="Egypt">Egypt</option>
        <option value="El Salvador">El Salvador</option>
        <option value="Equatorial Guinea">Equatorial Guinea</option>
        <option value="Eritrea">Eritrea</option>
        <option value="Estonia">Estonia</option>
        <option value="Ethiopia">Ethiopia</option>
        <option value="Falkland Islands">Falkland Islands</option>
        <option value="Faroe Islands">Faroe Islands</option>
        <option value="Fiji">Fiji</option>
        <option value="Finland">Finland</option>
        <option value="France">France</option>
        <option value="French Guiana">French Guiana</option>
        <option value="French Polynesia">French Polynesia</option>
        <option value="French Southern Ter">French Southern Ter</option>
        <option value="Gabon">Gabon</option>
        <option value="Gambia">Gambia</option>
        <option value="Georgia">Georgia</option>
        <option value="Germany">Germany</option>
        <option value="Ghana">Ghana</option>
        <option value="Gibraltar">Gibraltar</option>
        <option value="Great Britain">Great Britain</option>
        <option value="Greece">Greece</option>
        <option value="Greenland">Greenland</option>
        <option value="Grenada">Grenada</option>
        <option value="Guadeloupe">Guadeloupe</option>
        <option value="Guam">Guam</option>
        <option value="Guatemala">Guatemala</option>
        <option value="Guinea">Guinea</option>
        <option value="Guyana">Guyana</option>
        <option value="Haiti">Haiti</option>
        <option value="Hawaii">Hawaii</option>
        <option value="Honduras">Honduras</option>
        <option value="Hong Kong">Hong Kong</option>
        <option value="Hungary">Hungary</option>
        <option value="Iceland">Iceland</option>
        <option value="India">India</option>
        <option value="Indonesia">Indonesia</option>
        <option value="Iran">Iran</option>
        <option value="Iraq">Iraq</option>
        <option value="Ireland">Ireland</option>
        <option value="Isle of Man">Isle of Man</option>
        <option value="Israel">Israel</option>
        <option value="Italy">Italy</option>
        <option value="Jamaica">Jamaica</option>
        <option value="Japan">Japan</option>
        <option value="Jordan">Jordan</option>
        <option value="Kazakhstan">Kazakhstan</option>
        <option value="Kenya">Kenya</option>
        <option value="Kiribati">Kiribati</option>
        <option value="Korea North">Korea North</option>
        <option value="Korea Sout">Korea South</option>
        <option value="Kuwait">Kuwait</option>
        <option value="Kyrgyzstan">Kyrgyzstan</option>
        <option value="Laos">Laos</option>
        <option value="Latvia">Latvia</option>
        <option value="Lebanon">Lebanon</option>
        <option value="Lesotho">Lesotho</option>
        <option value="Liberia">Liberia</option>
        <option value="Libya">Libya</option>
        <option value="Liechtenstein">Liechtenstein</option>
        <option value="Lithuania">Lithuania</option>
        <option value="Luxembourg">Luxembourg</option>
        <option value="Macau">Macau</option>
        <option value="Macedonia">Macedonia</option>
        <option value="Madagascar">Madagascar</option>
        <option value="Malaysia">Malaysia</option>
        <option value="Malawi">Malawi</option>
        <option value="Maldives">Maldives</option>
        <option value="Mali">Mali</option>
        <option value="Malta">Malta</option>
        <option value="Marshall Islands">Marshall Islands</option>
        <option value="Martinique">Martinique</option>
        <option value="Mauritania">Mauritania</option>
        <option value="Mauritius">Mauritius</option>
        <option value="Mayotte">Mayotte</option>
        <option value="Mexico">Mexico</option>
        <option value="Midway Islands">Midway Islands</option>
        <option value="Moldova">Moldova</option>
        <option value="Monaco">Monaco</option>
        <option value="Mongolia">Mongolia</option>
        <option value="Montserrat">Montserrat</option>
        <option value="Morocco">Morocco</option>
        <option value="Mozambique">Mozambique</option>
        <option value="Myanmar">Myanmar</option>
        <option value="Nambia">Nambia</option>
        <option value="Nauru">Nauru</option>
        <option value="Nepal">Nepal</option>
        <option value="Netherland Antilles">Netherland Antilles</option>
        <option value="Netherlands (Holland, Europe)">Netherlands (Holland, Europe)</option>
        <option value="Nevis">Nevis</option>
        <option value="New Caledonia">New Caledonia</option>
        <option value="New Zealand">New Zealand</option>
        <option value="Nicaragua">Nicaragua</option>
        <option value="Niger">Niger</option>
        <option value="Nigeria">Nigeria</option>
        <option value="Niue">Niue</option>
        <option value="Norfolk Island">Norfolk Island</option>
        <option value="Norway">Norway</option>
        <option value="Oman">Oman</option>
        <option value="Pakistan">Pakistan</option>
        <option value="Palau Island">Palau Island</option>
        <option value="Palestine">Palestine</option>
        <option value="Panama">Panama</option>
        <option value="Papua New Guinea">Papua New Guinea</option>
        <option value="Paraguay">Paraguay</option>
        <option value="Peru">Peru</option>
        <option value="Philippines">Philippines</option>
        <option value="Pitcairn Island">Pitcairn Island</option>
        <option value="Poland">Poland</option>
        <option value="Portugal">Portugal</option>
        <option value="Puerto Rico">Puerto Rico</option>
        <option value="Qatar">Qatar</option>
        <option value="Republic of Montenegro">Republic of Montenegro</option>
        <option value="Republic of Serbia">Republic of Serbia</option>
        <option value="Reunion">Reunion</option>
        <option value="Romania">Romania</option>
        <option value="Russia">Russia</option>
        <option value="Rwanda">Rwanda</option>
        <option value="St Barthelemy">St Barthelemy</option>
        <option value="St Eustatius">St Eustatius</option>
        <option value="St Helena">St Helena</option>
        <option value="St Kitts-Nevis">St Kitts-Nevis</option>
        <option value="St Lucia">St Lucia</option>
        <option value="St Maarten">St Maarten</option>
        <option value="St Pierre &amp; Miquelon">St Pierre &amp; Miquelon</option>
        <option value="St Vincent &amp; Grenadines">St Vincent &amp; Grenadines</option>
        <option value="Saipan">Saipan</option>
        <option value="Samoa">Samoa</option>
        <option value="Samoa American">Samoa American</option>
        <option value="San Marino">San Marino</option>
        <option value="Sao Tome &amp; Principe">Sao Tome &amp; Principe</option>
        <option value="Saudi Arabia">Saudi Arabia</option>
        <option value="Senegal">Senegal</option>
        <option value="Serbia">Serbia</option>
        <option value="Seychelles">Seychelles</option>
        <option value="Sierra Leone">Sierra Leone</option>
        <option value="Singapore">Singapore</option>
        <option value="Slovakia">Slovakia</option>
        <option value="Slovenia">Slovenia</option>
        <option value="Solomon Islands">Solomon Islands</option>
        <option value="Somalia">Somalia</option>
        <option value="South Africa">South Africa</option>
        <option value="Spain">Spain</option>
        <option value="Sri Lanka">Sri Lanka</option>
        <option value="Sudan">Sudan</option>
        <option value="Suriname">Suriname</option>
        <option value="Swaziland">Swaziland</option>
        <option value="Sweden">Sweden</option>
        <option value="Switzerland">Switzerland</option>
        <option value="Syria">Syria</option>
        <option value="Tahiti">Tahiti</option>
        <option value="Taiwan">Taiwan</option>
        <option value="Tajikistan">Tajikistan</option>
        <option value="Tanzania">Tanzania</option>
        <option value="Thailand">Thailand</option>
        <option value="Togo">Togo</option>
        <option value="Tokelau">Tokelau</option>
        <option value="Tonga">Tonga</option>
        <option value="Trinidad &amp; Tobago">Trinidad &amp; Tobago</option>
        <option value="Tunisia">Tunisia</option>
        <option value="Turkey">Turkey</option>
        <option value="Turkmenistan">Turkmenistan</option>
        <option value="Turks &amp; Caicos Is">Turks &amp; Caicos Is</option>
        <option value="Tuvalu">Tuvalu</option>
        <option value="Uganda">Uganda</option>
        <option value="Ukraine">Ukraine</option>
        <option value="United Arab Emirates">United Arab Emirates</option>
        <option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option>
        <option value="United States of America">United States of America</option>
        <option value="Uruguay">Uruguay</option>
        <option value="Uzbekistan">Uzbekistan</option>
        <option value="Vanuatu">Vanuatu</option>
        <option value="Vatican City State">Vatican City State</option>
        <option value="Venezuela">Venezuela</option>
        <option value="Vietnam">Vietnam</option>
        <option value="Virgin Islands (Brit)">Virgin Islands (Brit)</option>
        <option value="Virgin Islands (USA)">Virgin Islands (USA)</option>
        <option value="Wake Island">Wake Island</option>
        <option value="Wallis &amp; Futana Is">Wallis &amp; Futana Is</option>
        <option value="Yemen">Yemen</option>
        <option value="Zaire">Zaire</option>
        <option value="Zambia">Zambia</option>
        <option value="Zimbabwe">Zimbabwe</option>
        </select><br><br>

    </div><br>


            <!-- Mark Applied Country  -->


    <b style="text-height:50%">Mark Applied Country:</b><br>

    <input type="text" style="height:10px;width:50%" id="selected_applied" name="applied_selected_values" value="selected_applied" disabled /> <br/>
        <select name="markappliedcountry" id="appliedcountry" style="width:40%" multiple >
        <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
        <option value="Albania">Albania</option>
        <option value="Algeria">Algeria</option>
        <option value="American">American Samoa</option>
        <option value="Andorra">Andorra</option>
        <option value="Angola">Angola</option>
        <option value="Anguilla">Anguilla</option>
        <option value="Antigua">Antigua &amp; Barbuda</option>
        <option value="Argentina">Argentina</option>
        <option value="Armenia">Armenia</option>
        <option value="Yemen">Yemen</option>
        <option value="Zaire">Zaire</option>
        <option value="Zambia">Zambia</option>
        <option value="Zimbabwe">Zimbabwe</option>
        </select><br/><br/>


    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function() {
  $('#yescountry').on('change', function() {
    $('#selected_yes').val($(this).val());
  });

  $('#nocountry').on('change', function() {
    $('#selected_no').val($(this).val());
  });

  $('#appliedcountry').on('change', function() {
    $('#selected_applied').val($(this).val());
  });

});
</script>

<script>
function disableNo() {
    document.getElementById("nocountry").required = false;
    document.getElementById("marknodate").required = false;      
}

function disableYes() {
    document.getElementById("yescountry").required = false;
    document.getElementById("markyesdate").required = false;
    document.getElementById("markyesproof").required = false;      
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I have shortened the select options due to the shortage of character limit. But, one out of the three select menus has all the options. So, you can copy those if you want to.